# Java Send message on Foreign JMS Server/Queue

Tags: java, jms, weblogic

I need to send a message from my web application to a foreign JMS server.

I'm using WebLogic and I've already configured a Foreign JMS Server/ConnectionFactory/Queue.

Regarding the Java code, should [this code](https://blogs.oracle.com/soaproactive/entry/jms_step_2_using_the) works also for a foreign JMS server?

I've tried, but I got an error, but... should it works?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually yes, it is expected to work because JMS client that you configured should hide from you the gory details of transport and inter-process and inter-computer communication. Just make sure that other side is available and accessible via network. First check `ping`, then check firewall definition (if there is a firewall between two sides.)

Comment: Ok thank you, the error I got is "Username or Password not valid" on ctx.lookup(JMS_FACTORY); but the username and password are ok! I can connect to the server with the same credentials! :(